# Specific word for social app user?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a specific word to describe **people who are active on social media apps:** FB, Whatsapp, etc.

The nearest word that I found while searching online is **netizen**. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/netizen) describes it as:

> a person who uses the internet

But, it does not fit the idea I want to represent:

> ______ are human beings without four limbs. They demand and demand, but can't act in real life.

Comment: What is wrong with *social-media users* or perhaps simply *users* ?

Comment: I found "onliner" at https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/netizen.html

Comment: @k1eran social media user is a sentence in itself.

Comment: @aparente001 onliner or netizen are those people who gets online. They does not mean social media user.

Comment: I don't find it satisfying either for what you described.  Hmm, maybe you'll have to coin a new word.

Comment: How about "applicant"?

Comment: Or maybe "appetizer"?

Comment: Do you want to include people who use a web browser to access social media sites or just those who use dedicated apps like the Facebook phone app?

Comment: Macmillan has ["twitterholic"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/people-who-use-social-media) and there are probably similar terms for other individual apps/sites. But not aware of a general term.

Comment: Perhaps terminally online?

Answer (score -1):

What about **social networker**: https://www.wikihow.com/Be-a-Social-Networker

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't comprise element of online.

Comment: I don't understand. This answers your question. You did not ask for the term to include "online". Also, if you know what a social network is, it cannot be other than online! So it in fact includes the concept that the person is online, because these apps are internet-based.

Comment: Social network need not necessarily be online. The word network was very well used for real life relationships especially in business and marketing domain. Likewise, social network is very well use for real like network. Also, it is readily understood that I am looking for element of virtual world i.e. online in my question. One does not use apps/application without getting online.

Comment: Of course, but that is the point. Now "social netwoker" means **someone who (regularly) uses an online social netwroking app.**

Comment: Yes, you got it right. So, I am looking for a word which describes the concept - *online social networking app user.*

Comment: The word is "social networker" -- it now includes the concept of online. But you may want to make it explicit and say "online social networker". Please see the line I posted in the answer: https://www.wikihow.com/Be-a-Social-Networker

Comment: I'm happy for your interest :) but "Social network user" in itself is entire sentence. If you read my questions again I am looking for a word for a **user** of **social network application.** So, here Social Network is just a platform. I have also given an example for **Internet User**. They are called Netizen (mostly in Asian countries: Singapore, China etc.).

Comment: "Social networker" is a compound word, not a sentence. I still don't get what is the problem with it. Do you want a word with no space in it?

Comment: Here is the problem:  [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/487886/specific-word-for-social-app-user/487887?noredirect=1#comment1178184_487887). Also, if you check the wikipedia page on **social network**, please read [History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network#History) section. Lastly, in your local community you may have multiple **social groups**, if you wish to interact, then the interaction would be called "social networking". Whereas, social networker is the participant.

Comment: So, your suggestion: **social networker** has the element of real-life situation and not **online.** But, few websites loosely use it in order to fill the missing word.

Comment: Okay. I understand you now. I would make clear in the context that we are talking about computers and internet. Then the phrase "social networker" would give you the exact meaning you want. Otherwise you could say "facebookers, tweeters and the rest..." or similar description.

Comment: I thought meaning was implicit because I again iterate that such app/application are used with internet. So, normally people do understand that here word has to be inline with Internet. Also, one should know that it is a single-word request and a not phrase-request

Comment: @GATECSE To a sociologist, "social networks" includes real-life communities. But to most people, the term has these days come to mean "online social networks" specifically. So the context where the term will be used is important.

Comment: @GATECSE Please don't be so problematic. "Social networker" is a compound word. It includes the concept of online and answers your question. If you don't like it that is another matter. **But if you finally decided to use "social networker" you would be surprised that everybody reading your text would know that you mean "facebook, twitter, etc. user".** That was my last comment on this post.

Comment: I like "Social Networker", brings to mind  the term "Social disease". Look it up if you are too young to remember. Appropriate.